# Pygame game not starting

Tags: python, pygame

So the idea is the game will open up to menu where the users can select a level, Easy, Medium, Hard, or exit the game. Right now all that happens is that the game opens to a black screen the size of my game (1024, 768) where the close, maximize, and minimize aren't clickable. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import pygame, random, os, sys

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
YELLOW = (255, 200, 0)

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 320))
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 20)
menu_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 40)

currentLevel = 0

pygame.display.set_caption("Mazer")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1040, 768))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 15, 15)

    def move(self, dx, dy):
        if dx != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(dx, 0)
        if dy != 0:
            self.move_single_axis(0, dy)

    def move_single_axis(self, dx, dy):

        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy

        for wall in walls:
            if self.rect.colliderect(wall.rect):
                if dx > 0:
                    self.rect.right = wall.rect.left
                if dx < 0:
                    self.rect.left = wall.rect.right
                if dy > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = wall.rect.top
                if dy < 0:
                    self.rect.top = wall.rect.bottom

# Nice class to hold a wall rect
class Wall(object):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

class Finish(object):

    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(pos[0], pos[1], 16, 16)

class Option:
    hovered = False
    def __init__(self, text, pos):
        self.text = text
        self.pos = pos
        self.set_rect()
        self.draw()
    def draw(self):
        self.set_rend()
        screen.blit(self.rend, self.rect)
    def set_rend(self):
        self.rend = menu_font.render(self.text, True, self.get_color())
    def get_color(self):
        if self.hovered:
            return (255, 255, 255)
        else:
            return (100, 100, 100)
    def set_rect(self):
        self.set_rend()
        self.rect = self.rend.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = self.pos

options = [Option("Easy", (140, 105)), Option("Medium", (135, 155)),
           Option("Hard", (145, 205)), Option("Exit", (145, 255))]

def Menu():
    running2 = True
    while running2:
        clock.tick(60)
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        mouseclick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit(0)
        for option in options:
            if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                option.hovered = True
                if mouseclick[0] == 1:
                    if option.text == "Easy":
                        global currentlevel
                        currentlevel = 0
                        main()
                    elif option.text == "Medium":
                        currentlevel = 1
                        main()
                    elif option.text == "Hard":
                        currentlevel = 2
                        main()
                    else:
                        running2 = False
            else:
                option.hovered = False
            option.draw()
        #screen.blit(, (350, 50))
        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit(0)


levels = [[
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                           P                                                  W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                            F                                                 W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "W                                                                              W",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ],
    [
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W   WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W         P        W",
    "W                  W",
    "W   WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W   WWWWWWWWWWWWW  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W         F        W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ],
    [
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W         P        W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "W         F        W",
    "W                  W",
    "W                  W",
    "WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW",
    ]]

def load_level(level):
    walls = []
    players = []
    finishes = []

    x = y = 0
    for row in levels[level]:
        for col in row:
            if col == "W":
                walls.append(Wall((x, y)))
            if col == "P":
                players.append(Player((x, y)))
            if col == "F":
                finishes.append(Finish((x, y)))
            x += 16
        y += 16
        x = 0
    return walls, players, finishes

walls, players, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)
running = True

def main():
    while running:
        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.event.pump()
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and e.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False

        for option in options:
            if option.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                option.hovered = True
            else:
                option.hovered = False
            option.draw()

        # Move the player if an arrow key is pressed
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            player.move(-2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            player.move(2, 0)
        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            player.move(0, -2)
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            player.move(0, 2)

        for player in players:
            for finish in finishes:
                if player.rect.colliderect(finish.rect): 
                    currentLevel += 1
                    walls, players, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)

        screen.fill((BLACK))
        for wall in walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (WHITE), wall.rect)
        for player in players:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (YELLOW), player.rect)
        for finish in finishes:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (GREEN), finish.rect)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At no point in your program are you starting the main() function or anything else for that matter.

A common piece found at the bottom of many python scripts is:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is used to kick start everything if the script is the top level python file

include this at the bottom and this will get you started.

Once you've done this you'll find that many of your variables called in functions are local (I'm guessing the whole issue is based on the fact you wrote the program and then tried to tie everything up in functions later) so you will need to declare them as globals, but this is outside the scope of this question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I did that and moved the 'running = True' into the main loop but now it's crashing on startup and giving an error on the 'for player in players:' loop in main, stating that - "local variable 'players' referenced before assignment".

Comment: Has the load_level function been executed before you reach that main loop?

Comment: Just before the main function there's the line
        walls, players, finishes = load_level(currentLevel)
if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

To declare them as globals write this after the line: `def main():` :

```
    global running, players, finishes, walls, currentLevel
```